# Error:(19) No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android' when trying to install ADMOB

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I'm trying to include Admob in my app. So I already registered my account in Admob. I plan to use it without Firebase (but I could do it if needed). So I followed this :

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

And i tried to add this into the **app.gradle** :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
```

And it doesn't work. Here is the **app.gradle** :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'junit:junit:4.12'


    }
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.14.1'
    compile 'com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.18.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.testng:testng:6.10'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.6.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'


    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'

    //testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.10'
    compile files('C:/Users/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/xxx/libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('C:/Users/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/xxx/libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('C:/Users/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/Bxx/libs/mail.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.0'



}
```

And here is the project gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        //mavenCentral()
        jcenter()


    }

    dependencies {

        //compile "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:JitPack.1.19.0"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'





        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And when I try to compile the error sends me right away to the manifest :

> Error:(19) No resource identifier found for attribute 'appComponentFactory' in package 'android'
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Those are in red in the manifest , but not only:

```
android:allowBackup="true"
android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

I tried to change the versions of google services, the versions of the app indexing, the version of the adds. I have gone through a lot of posts but nothing seem to work. Either the SDK versions are not the same, I tried to downgrade it to 26 but android told me 26 wasn't found in the directory

Could someone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by installing firebase and tweaking the versions.